# Python optparse without add_option

Tags: python, optparse

Is there a possibility to use optparse **without having to define every single possible option?** I'd like my program to treat every value as a string.

Example:
`python program.py --arg1 something --file test.txt`

I would expect optparse to store it under
`options['arg1']` and options`['file']`

Then I could call it adding any argument I want, like:
`python program.py --arg1 something --file test.txt --something value`
and it would just add it to the options without me touching the code

`options['arg1']` and `options['file']` and `options['something']`

I must maintain compatibility with Python 2.6 and 2.7 so I guess I cannot use argparse

Cheers

Comment: Note: You can `pip install argparse` for Python 2.6.

Comment: Can I solve my problem in argparse?

Comment: Not really.  You might use `parser.parse_known_args`, which returns a tuple of the parsed namespace and a list of the undefined options, but those extra options would still need more post-processing.  I was just pointing out that using Python 2.6 doesn't necessarily mean you're stuck with `optparse`.